# Facebook native Android API generates error for non-admin users

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I wanted to obtain user access token for my application to access logged-in user's photos etc. I created a [login button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330330/how-to-get-facebook-user-access-token-in-android) as given on facebook android SDK tutorials. I am able to get access token for my admin account which created this application on facebook.

But when I login with any other account, it throws following exception:

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Ideally, all other persons should be able to login to this app. I am testing it on an emulator. Could it be a problem?

```
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352): Exception during service
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352): com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: Invalid application 332039450257790
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:74)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:208)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:267)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:28)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.SingleMethodRunner.a(SingleMethodRunner.java:125)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:274)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:175)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:218)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:38)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue$3.run(OrcaServiceQueue.java:169)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 01:29:09.618: W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(352):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352): Failed to send
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352): com.facebook.orca.ops.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:610)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:40)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation$2.run(OrcaServiceOperation.java:575)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 01:29:09.628: W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(352):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There are two things I need to look into which might have caused this error: 1) I have disabled sandbox mode for my app now. 2) I have not published my app for review which might cause this problem, though I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually during app creation, I had wrongly selected 'sandboxed' mode which restricts app's access only to developers added in app configuration page. So after disabling this mode, I was able to generate access token for other users too.